# how to give different .mat-ink-bar for different mat-tabs?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

How to give different `.mat-ink-bar` for different `mat-tabs`?

**For example:**

For content 1 the `.mat-ink-bar` should be **green** and for content 2 the `.mat-ink-bar` should be **red**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child(index)`
like

```
mat-tabs .mat-ink-bar{
color: green;
}


mat-tabs .mat-ink-bar:nth-child(2){ /* this will override default*/
color: red;
}
```